# What might the names "Loeffler" and "Loeffelmacher" mean?

Tags: person-names

This question is not *so much* about language and grammar, but what I want to know is what could possibly be the origin of these two last names? Loeffler is a fairly common last name, Loeffelmacher is not. Loeffelmacher means "spoon maker" from my translation, I assume Loeffler means something similar.

But there's no possible way spoon-making was a job. Does it imply a person that does woodworking? Or a person who does silversmithing? How about Loeffler?

Or is it possible that there's some cultural significance to spoons which I am not aware of?

Comment: Spoon-making *was* a profession. Remember: These names stem from a time when *everything* was hand-made. Spoons were either wood, horn or metal.

Comment: so cool @Stephie! i figured a spoonmaker would have diversified into other wooden items, so why pick the spoon as the namesake?

Comment: my doctor's name is Knoepflmacher, and my podiatrist's name is Schumacher. i'm gonna collect them all :-)

Comment: Consider this as  the first stages of specialization: If you make *only* buttons / spoons / bowls / ... you can streamline the process and get really fast. Assuming that you have a large enough customer base, of course.

Comment: @Stephie I think also guilds played a role in maintaining such specialization, because they fixed prices. In a fluctuating price economy, it makes more sense have a broad base of woodworking knowledge and make whatever item is in highest demand at the time. But with long-term price fixing in place, you can pick one item and stick with it.

Comment: sehr interessant @Atsby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Duden – *Das Lexikon der Familiennamen,* the name *Löffler* (Middle High German: *leffeler*) means *Löffelmacher* and it is indeed a job title for a craftsman who makes wooden spoons.

Comment: amazing! never heard of Das Lexikon der Familiennamen, but as a beginner student auf Deutsch, i probably would not have known to look for it. thank you!